# Get Industries from LinkedIn API for a Given Company

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to tag list of companies to their industry type.

I have LinkedIn client id and secret key. I was able to generate the access_token. i'm using V2 LinkedIn API and was wondering if there is a sample code to pass company name and return their industry name.

I have constructed the URI as below based on the API docs and it doesn't seem right. Appreciate your help

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/search?q=companiesV2&baseSearchParams.keywords=LinkedIn%20Corporation&companySearchParams.facetIndustry%5B0%5D&facetCompanyCountryRegion%5B0%5D=us:84&oauth2_access_token=Access_token
```

I get the following error.. Can you please help troubleshoot

```
{"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Not enough permissions to access: GET-companiesV2 /search","status":403}
```

Comment: What permission scopes are you requesting with your OAuth access token?

Comment: @Christopher Ou  I have following  r_emailaddress, r_liteprofile and w_member_social.. Also do we have a API support number/contact from LinkedIn? This is currently blocker for my APP development and was curious if i can get it resolved ASAP by means of contacting anyone within API team at LinkedIn?

Comment: Company Search is a private API and not available via the permissions you've listed. You may need to submit a request to the Marketing Developer Program: https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner/marketing-developer-program

Comment: @Christopher Ou. Sadly, I have submitted this request a week back and still waiting for their response. Is there anything we can do expedite this? Also, does this API have Bulk_fetch option at all??

Comment: @Christopher Ou or LinkedIn experts can you please let me know if i can expedite my request for company search API access please. It has been 2 weeks+ i'm waiting to hear back on my access request for marketing solutions platform

Comment: The expected response time is 30 days -- though we are currently receiving a large number of requests and responses may be delayed. Appreciate your patience as your app is reviewed by our teams here.